# Radio Button List - small text alignment issue?

Tags: html, alignment, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list that has buttons like this:
http://imageshack.us/f/545/capture1jtr.png/

However, I notice a small alignemnt issue .. I want the second line of text to be after the "radio button's circle" ... How do I do this ??

I have absolutely no idea!

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Give this a try in the css**

```
<style type="text/css">
 table.radioButton input
 {    
      float: left;
 }

 table.radioButton label
 {    
      margin-left: 25px;
      display: block;
 }
</style>
```

**And the in the .aspx**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" CssClass="radioButton" ....>
```